# Android in-App purchase Item not found

Tags: android, android-billing

i tried to implement in app purchase in adroid. I have everything set up correctly... I use following code :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.main_purchase_yes:
        if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(TopOption.this, "android.test.purchased"); 
            // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or android.test.refunded or com.blundell.item.passport
        } else {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(TopOption.this, "Can't purchase on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg.getXOffset() / 2, msg.getYOffset() / 2);

            msg.show();
            Log.i(TAG,"Can't purchase on this device");
            // XXX press button before service started will disable when it shouldnt
        }

        break;
    default:
        // nada
        Log.i(TAG,"default. ID: "+v.getId());
        break;
    }
```

But if I set the product id instead of "android.test.purchased" to "com.company.item.itemID"
the response i got from the store is ItemNotFound? DOes someone know what to do with this?

in my manifest.xml I set everything , like permission, service and other....... 
And everywhere i have set com.companyname.AppID.
On google pla i Have set the app. and the item i set as published.

Does anyone know what to do with this?

Update:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.companyname.productid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/newname"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".TopOption"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".mygame"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".aboutclass"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

  <service android:name=".BillingService" />
  <receiver android:name=".BillingReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />         
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver> 

</application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: You can't be sure that you're doing everything, otherwise you won't be there. Please post most info, like your Manifest you are so sure about. Also please detail what process you went through on Google's site to register your In-App APK..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Export your app as an APK file.
2. Upload the APK to Google Play.
3. Sideload the same APK to your test device.
4. Wait an hour or so for Google Play to update its servers.
5. Test the installed APK.